# It skips it-statement when executing function in Pester, but shouldn't

Tags: powershell, testing, mocking, pester

I am trying to test a Function in an script file that is testing the connection to a PC. I am trying to do that by calling the mock "Test-Connection" from an other Script in an Pester Test.

When I run Temp.Testing.ps1

```
describe 'Test Error Handling' {
    $myDir = Split-Path -parent $PSCommandPath  
    $testFile = "$myDir\TryToRenameComputer.ps1"
    .$testFile

    mock 'Test-Connection' { $false }

    $pathForLogs = "C:\temp\Logs.txt"

    it 'exits if Test-Connection Failed'{
        TryToRenameComputer -OldName "OldName"
        Assert-MockCalled 'Test-Connection' -Times 1 -Scope It 
    }
}
```

TryToRenameComputer.ps1

```
function TryToRenameComputer {
    param([parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [string]$computerName)

    if (!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $computerName -Quiet)) {
        exit
    }
}
```

it skips the it-statement and shows me no errors. Only "Describing Test Error Handling".

Expected Result:
[image: Expected Result]

Actual Result:
[image: Actual Result]

I already tried running a other Function and it worked.
Also when I am running multiple it-statements all get skipped when I call the Function in 1 it-statement.
I also tried rewriting it so it is no function anymore and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely occurring because of the `exit` statement in your code. This is getting executed because in the `if` statement before it you are using `-not` via its shorthand of `!` to test for the result of `Test-Connection` and because your `Mock` sets `Test-Connection` to `$false`.

By using `exit` you are immediately terminating the PowerShell host, which is then stopping your tests from executing/completing.

Instead of using `exit` consider using `break` or `return` to stop the execution of the function without terminating the script. Or if you potentially do want to terminate the script, consider using `throw` as you can then stop the parent script when an exception has occurred.

You could then modify your tests to test for that `throw` as that is the result you expect to occur when `test-connection` returns `$false`. For example:

```bsh
function TryToRenameComputer {
    param([parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [string]$computerName)

    if (!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $computerName -Quiet)) {
        Thow "Could not connect to $computerName"
    }
}

describe 'Test Error Handling' {
    $myDir = Split-Path -parent $PSCommandPath  
    $testFile = "$myDir\TryToRenameComputer.ps1"
    .$testFile

    mock 'Test-Connection' { $false }

    $pathForLogs = "C:\temp\Logs.txt"

    it 'Throws an error if Test-Connection Failed'{
        { TryToRenameComputer -OldName "OldName" } | Should -Throw
        Assert-MockCalled 'Test-Connection' -Times 1 -Scope It 
    }
}
```

There's no easy way to handle `exit` in your tests and its generally a bit of an anti-pattern when you're writing code for automation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and tips to fix it! :)